# File locations in shell script property files

Tags: shell, properties-file

I have a property looks like below in property file and the properties are ready by "sourcing" in shell script.

```
MW_INSTALLER_11.6="/ade_autofs/scratch/test/installer/wls_generic.jar"
```

During sourcing, observing the below error and the variable is not read. 
Where all other properties are read perfectly fine.

```
./upgrade.properties: line 45: MW_INSTALLER_11.6=/ade_autofs/scratch/test/installer/wls_generic.jar: No such file or directory
```

The file mentioned above is present specified path. Observing same issue with or without double quotes. 
What is the right way to add the file location in property file?

Code around above specified property in property files

```
POST_UPGRADE_ANT_OPTIONS=
MW_INSTALLER_11.6="/ade_autofs/scratch/test/installer/wls_generic.jar"
NO_OF_RELEASES_TO_UPGRADE=1
```

Code around sourcing property file in shell script, here  $1 represents property file

```
echo "Reading properties file $1" | tee -a $LOG_DRIVER_FILE

. ./$1

UPGRADE_PROPERTIES_FILE=$1
```

thanks In Advance, soman

Comment: Please show the complete code if possible, or at least the code around that line. There's nothing wrong with the line itself.

Comment: @JoSo you mean code around when sourcing properties file in shell script?

Comment: Around the properties file. And maybe also show how you source that file. Please don't let us guess what you're doing wrong. Just show as much as reasonable of the thing that could be relevant.

Comment: @JoSo Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited post to add code around in property file and shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Issue is due to the variable name contains "." [dot]

after changing from `MW_INSTALLER_11.6="/ade_autofs/scratch/test/installer/wls_generic.jar"`

to
`MW_INSTALLER_11_6="/ade_autofs/scratch/test/installer/wls_generic.jar"`

It worked fine.

Regards.